# How to UPDATE value in a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here I have some value stored in a table:

```
| points_id || user_id(fk) || point_hist |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      1    ||     10      ||    100     |  
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      2    ||     11      ||     30     |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      3    ||     12      ||     70     |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      4    ||     13      ||    200     |
```

Here if users awarded `100 points` and they already have `100 points` such as `points_id` 1.

I need a query to add their awarded 100 to their current 100 points to = 200 points.

here is my PHP:

```
<?php
    // see if the form has been completed
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    $username = "";
    $weight = "";
    $height = "";
    $weighthist = "";
    $id = "";

if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} 
    //$user_query=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users,points_history"); /* WHAT'S THE PURPOSE OF VARIABLE $username? */
    $user_query=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1"); 

/* check if the user exists in the database */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)) {
    $id = $row ["id"];
    $username = $row ["username"];
    $weight = $row["weight"];
    $points = $row['point_hist'];

    } /* END OF WHILE LOOP $user_query */

    $q12 = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM points_history WHERE id='$id'"); 
     /* check if the user exists in the database */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q12)) {
        $id = $row ["id"];
        $points = $row['point_hist'];
        } /* END OF WHILE LOOP $user_query */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $weighthist = $_POST['weighthist'];
    $point_hist = $_POST['point_hist'];

    $exists=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($exists)!=0) {
    /* update the description in the database */

    /* calculate score */
        $calweight = $weight - $weighthist; 
        $point_hist = $calweight * 10 + $points;

    mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO weighthistory (id, weighthist, date) VALUES ('$id','$weighthist',now())");

   // mysqli_query ($db_conx,"INSERT INTO  points_history (id, point_hist, date) VALUES ('$id','$point_hist',now())");


   /* UPDATE QUERY */

    // Update weight in the users table.
    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE users SET weight='$weighthist' WHERE id='$id'");

    mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE points_history SET point_hist='$point_hist' WHERE id='$id'");    

   /* END OF UPDATE QUERY */

    } /* END OF ELSE IF $exists NOT 0 */

    else { echo "the name does not exist";  }

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide us your code?

Comment: so you basically want `UPDATE table SET points_hist=points_hist+100 WHERE points_id=1` ?

Comment: @LoganWayne I just added my code.

Comment: Sidenote:don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. `mysql_` functions are unsafe and are prone to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: When you go into production consider removing your credentials...

Comment: _s(vote down)accept

I want to update points_history as when user has 100 points and they get 90 more next award I want it to add the 100 to the 90 then totals to 190 @grandmarshalbraev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed your ***MySQL*** with ***MySQLi***. Lets all convert them to ***MySQLi***. And let me try to clean up your code for better understanding.

Lets assume that your **check_login_status.php** looks like this:

```
<?php

$db_conx=mysqli_connect("studentnet","k1003140","iphone09","db_k1003140"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Your **main** code:

```
<?php

    include("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

    if(isset($_GET["u"])){
        $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    } 

    $username = "";

    $user_query=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1"); /* WHAT'S THE PURPOSE OF VARIABLE $username? */

    /* check if the user exists in the database */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)) {
        $id = $row ["id"];
        $username = $row ["username"];
        $weight = $row["weight"];
        $email = $row["email"];
        } /* END OF WHILE LOOP $user_query */

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $weight = $_POST['weight'];
        $weighthist = $_POST['weighthist'];
        $point_hist = $_POST['point_hist'];

        $exists=mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($exists)!=0) {
        /* update the description in the database */

        /* calculate score */
            $calweight = $weight - $weighthist;     
            $point_hist = $calweight * 10;

        mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO weighthistory (id, weighthist, date) VALUES ('$id','$weighthist',now())");

        mysqli_query ($db_conx,"INSERT INTO  points_history (id, point_hist, date) VALUES ('$id','$point_hist',now())");


       /* UPDATE QUERY */

       mysqli_query($db_conx,"UPDATE points_history SET point_hist='$TheUpdatedValue' WHERE id='$id'");

       /* END OF UPDATE QUERY */


        } /* END OF ELSE IF $exists NOT 0 */

        else { echo "the name does not exist";  }

} /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

?>
```

I think you haven't given the whole code. I just convert your code from mixed ***MySQL*** and ***MySQLi*** to ***MySQLi*** only.

Comment: I have just added my HTML, but the code you gave me it gave errors.

Comment: I need a query to update my score after the insert query

Comment: Tell me what table to update. So the two insert query at the bottom PHP page should not be alter? You just need update? When should the update happen?

Comment: @user3443701 Now that MySQLi is solved, next is the update query. Tell me the details, what table to update. And where will the data be coming from.

Comment: _s(vote down)accept

I want to update points_history as when user has 100 points and they get 90 more next award I want it to add the 100 to the 90 then totals to 190 @grandmarshalbraev

Comment: @user3443701 look at the updated answer. I inserted an example of UPDATE query after the INSERT query. Just set the condition you want for it.

Comment: now when I insert new score it changes the value to 0.

Comment: Did you change the query or you just paste the code I have provided?

Comment: I had to change the update method I will show you the Updated code.@grandmarshalbraev

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot, I changed the way I insert the score, so I inserted the score ROW when users register but then apply the update when they awarded new score. @grandmarshalbraev